# The limits of $ g_n (x):=n \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}(x)$ in weak* topology and in the sense of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

Define 
$$g_n (x) := n \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}(x)$$
then $g_n\in L^1 (\mathbb R)\subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})^*$, since $\|g_n\|_* = 1$, by weak-star compactness of the unit ball in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})^*$, we know there exists a subsequence 
$$g_{n_k} \xrightarrow{\;*\;} \mu \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})^*.$$

Now we also know that $g_n \rightarrow \delta_0$ in the sense of distributions. Is there any connection between $\mu$ and $\delta_0$? We know $\mu$ is a finite additive measure that is absolute continuous to the Lebesgue measure, thus it can not be $\delta_0$.

Comment: Here is another question: How do we know that the unit ball of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})^*$ is weak-* *sequentially compact*? Or is there any way to guarantee that $(g_n)$ has a convergent subsequence in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})^*$?

Comment: ah I see, I overlooked this, since $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable, so compact does not imply sequentially compact.

Comment: Although $(g_n)$ may not have a convergent subsequence, it has a convergent subnet. So let $\mu$ be a limit of a convergent subnet of $(g_n)$. Then $\mu$ is related to $\delta_0$ in such a way that $\mu(B) = \delta_0(B)$ for any Borel set $B$ such that $0 \notin \partial B$. This is a direct consequence of the Portmanteau theorem.

Comment: @Carl $L^1$ is certainly not reflexive. By "finite additive" the OP means that the space consists of objects which are not measures since they satisfy only finite additivity, not countable additivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was noted in comments, the unit ball of $(L^\infty)^*$ is **not** sequentially compact in the weak* topology. More specifically, your sequence $g_n$ **does not have any weak*-convergent subsequence**. Indeed, given any subsequence $g_{n_k}$, one can build an $L^\infty$ function $f$ (based on these indices $n_k$) such that $\int fg_{n_k}$ fails to have a limit. Here is a sketch:

(a) we may arrange that $n_{k+1}\ge 2n_k$ by extracting a further subsequence;
(b) let $f(x) = (-1)^k$ when $n_k<x^{-1}<n_{k+1}$;
(c) check that $\int fg_{n_k} \ge 1/3$ for even $n$ and  $\int fg_{n_k} \le -1/3$ for odd $k$.

But it's true that the sequence $\{g_n\}$ has a weak* *cluster point* $\mu\in(L^\infty)^*$, meaning that every weak* neighborhood of $\mu$ is visited by the sequence infinitely often. (I find the cluster point language easier to digest than subnets.) Any such cluster point (there's no uniqueness) has the property that
$$\mu(\phi) = \phi(0),\quad \forall \ \phi\in C(\mathbb R)$$
because $\int \phi g_n\to \phi(0)$ for continuous functions. Therefore: the restriction of any cluster point $\mu$ to the space of continuous functions agrees with the Dirac delta.

Informally speaking: continuous functions form a tiny slice of the incomprehensibly vast space $L^\infty$. The latter space has incomprehensibly many linear functionals that behave just like Dirac delta on continuous functions but act in different ways elsewhere in the space.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} n 1_{x \in [0,1/n]}= \delta(x)$ converges in $C^0(\mathbb{R})^*$. A question would be : to what subspace of $L^\infty$ can it be extended ? And to what subspace of $L^\infty$ the limit doesn't depend on the particular sequence $n 1_{x \in [0,1/n]}$ chosen to approximate $\delta$

Comment: Consider the functions for which 0 is a Lebesgue point.

Comment: Lebesgue point ? The second part is more or less obvious : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle \phi_n,f \rangle$ doesn't depend on the sequence $\phi_n \ge 0, \text{supp}(\phi_n) \to \{0\}, \int \phi_n(x)dx =1$  iff $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Yes, [Lebesgue point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point)

Comment: But it is not useful because it is just the definition. Is the subspace of $L^\infty$ such that "$\forall a, \lim_{n \to \infty}\langle f, n 1_{x -a\in [-1/n,1/n]}  \rangle$ converges" closed ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for the intuition at the end,  I understood what you are saying, but it seemed a bit counter intuitive since there are a lot more linear functionals for the continuous functions since $C_c$ is a smaller space than $L^\infty$, but from this it looks like a lot of different linear functionals on $L^\infty$ will become the "same" linear functional  $\delta_0$ for the continuous functions.

Comment: @Xiao Larger space $\implies$ more linear functionals. Consider than in finite dimensions, the dual of $n$-dimensional space is $n$-dimensional. 
 When different functionals are restricted to the smaller space, they may become the same.